# ServerName in sites-available doesn't match hosted site

Tags: apache-2.2

I have access to two different web servers that I did not setup (person who did set it up cannot be contacted) which host the same site on separate sub-domains except one is backup and used for designing new content, and the other is the live version. They host the sites at two different sub domains like so.

sub1.domain.com (live)
sub2.domain.com (backup)

I recently was looking at contingencies for if the system needs to be restarted and noticed that the backup site has an odd "sites-available" configuration. It lists an international domain (.nu) as the ServerName, as apposed to the expected sub2.domain.com. I checked the live server to see how it was configured, and the server name was as expected (sub1.domain.com).

I attempted to lookup the international domain but it is not reachable, and is actually available for purchase currently. Both sites are currently working, but I'm not sure how the backup server is actually available with this faulty server name.

Any tips as to how this is possibly working?

**Update**

```
<VirtualHost *:####>
        ServerAdmin my.email@domain.com
        ServerName sub.domain.nu

        DocumentRoot /home/userx/www
        <Directory /home/userx/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

#other sub directory configs 
#some error log statements are here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Would be best if you provided more details such as configuration.

Comment: Can't fit the whole config, but this is the 1st section of it. 

**added as an update as that looks neater**

Comment: check httpd.conf or other sites-enabled configuration files like 000-default.

Comment: The other default file was exactly the same, and there are no modules loaded into the httpd.conf. However, I did check out the etc/hosts file which included the IP address and proper subdomain and domain of the server. From my understanding (which is rather basic on the networking side) I'm guessing this is resolving the issue?

Comment: So your other config - default file - what does it have for ServerName? If it is the "same" but does not have ServerName or has a different value, then it confirms what I answered earlier.

Comment: By the same I mean the exact same, ServerName and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details such as complete configuration, I would venture to say it is working because sub2.domain.com DNS entry points to your server and your server has a default (i.e. no server name) configuration that is the same as the one for sub2.domain.com (which is probably also a default file location like /var/www/ or something).

Or simple as per the documentation, it uses a default configuration because there is no matching ServerName so it falls back:

> When using IP-based virtual hosting, the special name *default* can be
>   specified in which case this virtual host will match any IP address
>   that is not explicitly listed in another virtual host. In the absence
>   of any *default* virtual host the "main" server config, consisting of
>   all those definitions outside any VirtualHost section, is used when no
>   IP-match occurs. (But note that any IP address that matches a
>   NameVirtualHost directive will use neither the "main" server config
>   nor the *default* virtual host. See the name-based virtual hosting
>   documentation for further details.)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost